# Setting marks in tmux copy-mode buffer?

Tags: tmux

When using tmux in copy mode (vi mode), I'd like to set marks in the buffer, as I would do with vim

> (m +  to mark, ' +  to go to a mark. See vim :help mark).

...So it is easy to go back and forth between different positions in the buffer... 
Is that possible? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy-mode` doesn't support these kinds of markers.

Comment: sad to hear that...Thank for answering anyway